# How to structure a database on a server for multiple websites?

Tags: mysql, server, web

Apologies if this is quite a general question but I'm just not sure how to structure it. If I want to make multiple websites for different people on my server, how do I structure the database?

Would I have schemas for each site and then separate tables for every input? Or would I have a single table for an entire site and have different columns for each input? The latter doesn't seem to work because there would be a lot of empty columns for each input. But the first one seems a bit excessive? IE to have an entire table for one single input that won't have more than one record in it?

Comment: Question seem to be really broad. Please check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I would heavily advise against having data from different projects in a single database. Isolation offers a strong bonus to security. You'd be opening yourself up to a whole world of legal pain if your database was comprised by one client's site, thus giving up ALL data held across the database.

Is there anything preventing you from creating a separate database for each site?

Comment: Ah I see, sorry was just a misunderstanding on my side.